# When I use #! with my URLs the same content appears, could this hurt SEO?

Tags: seo, url, hash

My website URL contains a `#!` (hashbang):

```
www.example.com/index.html
www.example.com/index.html#!
```

When user visit either two URLs above, the same content appears.

Does Google consider both URLs the same or is there a difference and could, as a result, a negative effect in organic traffic be observed?

Comment: "My website URL contains" - by that you mean you are actually linking to the URLs that contain `#!` throughout your site?

Comment: While it  doesn't address `#!` URLs, this question has info on how Google processes duplicate content and how it could affect SEO: [What is duplicate content and how can I avoid being penalized for it on my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35652/what-is-duplicate-content-and-how-can-i-avoid-being-penalized-for-it-on-my-site)

Answer (score 2):

Google understands that anchor links are the same page with or without the anchor.

Example: example.com/page and example.com/page#div

Google understands that these are the same pages. And so there is no duplicate content issues.

Anchor links are a very common and useful URL protocol across the web. It can be very helpful for example.com/kittens to link to example.com/animals#cats so that the user can navigate to the related cats content in that div. Linking to your content in this way should be perfectly fine.

---

Wikipedia links to anchors from different pages. And Wikipedia ranks very highly on Google.

https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Link#Linking_to_anchors

links to:

https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Section#Section_linking

Comment: Thanks for reply. I can understand no duplicate content issues but Please ensure me, these URLs will not divert traffic in two ways. www.example.com/index.html
www.example.com/index.html#!

Comment: It's possible that Google may send traffic to index.html#! if it thinks that the content in that div is relevant to the search terms. There are instances where Google will link users to a div on Wikipedia such as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat#Health - If there really is no reason for having links such as index#! then it's probably best if you don't link to your pages this way. Will it have some major negative SEO implication if you do? Probably not